# Swift - Replace the 2nd character of a string

Tags: swift, string, replace

I have an array with a set of three-letter words that will be the foundation of a game I am working on. I am trying to replace the second character of all these words with an underscore in my **UILabel**. The user will have to tap the correct vowel to complete the word.

```
let games: [Game] = {
    let firstGame = Game(question: "1", answer: "BAT", choice_1: "A", choice_2: "O", choice_3: "U", choice_4: "E", image: "_bat", audio: "bat.wav")
    let secondGame = Game(question: "2", answer: "BIN", choice_1: "A", choice_2: "O", choice_3: "U", choice_4: "E", image: "_bin", audio: "bin.wav")
    let thirdGame = Game(question: "3", answer: "BOX", choice_1: "A", choice_2: "O", choice_3: "U", choice_4: "E", image: "_box", audio: "box.wav")
    return [firstGame, secondGame, thirdGame]
}()
```

I found the *`replacingOccurrences`* functionality, but this one only replaces a single letter or set. What is the easiest way to replace all my vowels with the `_` character.

```
var game: Game? {
    didSet {

        questionLabel.text = "Question \(String(describing: game!.question)) of 10"

        if (game?.image) != nil {
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: (game?.image)!)
        }

        if let answerContent = game?.answer {
            answerField.text = answerContent.replacingOccurrences(of: "A", with: "_")
            answerField.addTextSpacing()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Loop for all your vowels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace vowels…

```
let vowels = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "AEIOU")
var string = "CAT"

if let range = string.rangeOfCharacter(from: vowels) {
    string.replaceSubrange(range, with: "_")
}

print(string) // C_T
```

Replace second character…

```
let start = string.index(after: string.startIndex)

// Only 1 character, so using a closed range with start == end
let range = start...start  

string.replaceSubrange(range, with: "_")

print(string)  // C_T
```

Comment: but what if string is `CTA`, it will be `CT_`

Comment: Thanks for adding a second piece of code to do the same thing for the index!